# Where is the switch or fuse box that will turn off the electrified fence in Hero's Pass?

Tags: borderlands-2

Where is the switch or fuse box that will turn off the electrified fence in [Hero's Pass?](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hero%27s_Pass)

Hero's Pass is one of the locations that you have to go through in *[The Talon of God](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Talon_of_God)* mission. When I was playing through *The Talon of God*, I tried tracing the power lines but I haven't found the switch or fuse box that will turn off the electricity.

[image: electrified fence in Hero's Pass]

#### Map view:

[image]

Comment: I was just going to suggest following the cable, but you apparently already did that.  Follow it again?

Comment: @MBraedley "*Follow it again?*" I'd do that, but this electrified fence's power cable is probably the longest in all of Pandora. It does not help that a lot of enemies are in the way too. I asked this question to save myself time, in case someone else has already found the switch or fuse box. =)

Comment: The loot was pretty average when I opened it on first playthrough

Comment: @DanielPowell I had the same experience. All loot were of common rarity when I found them. (I didn't have the Vault Hunter's Relic equipped.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to cross the first bridge and then immediately turn to the right. You'll find the fuse box out on that ledge, it's facing the cliff.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's after the second bridge. Turn right and walk along the ledge a short way.

Comment: do you use AutoCAD?